# Mapping a range in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a simple way of mapping a range to another kind of range in ruby without iterating over the whole range? 
Basically what I'm trying to achieve is this

```
## mapping this
range = 1..5
## into this
date_range = (1.year.ago)..(5.years.ago)
```

The best I came up with was this:

```
(range.begin.years.ago)..(range.end.years.ago)
```

Is there a method that would let me do something like:

```
range.map {|e| e.years.ago}
```

Comment: `(range.begin.years.ago)..(range.end.years.ago)` looks ok for me.

Comment: or `Range.new(range.begin.years.ago, range.end.years.ago, range.exclude_end?)` if inclusive / exclusive may vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently (Ruby 2.2.2) no better way than just

```
(range.begin.years.ago)..(range.end.years.ago)
```

If you look into the [documentation of Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Range.html), you see that none of the methods directly implement something like that.

Then, there is the included module `Enumerable` which already looses the range semantics (being defined by first and last element).

You could monkey-patch it yourself like:

```
class Range
  def rmap(&b)
    Range.new(yield(self.begin), yield(self.end), exclude_end?)
  end 
end
```

and then do (`years.ago` requires ActiveSupport/Rails):

```
(1..5).rmap { | a | a.years.ago }
```

Obviously, the block has to yield values suitable for creating a range.

Comment: I'm using Ruby 2.1.5 on windows and `(range.begin.years.ago)..(range.end.years.ago)` does not work. There is no `years` method for Fixnums in ruby.

Comment: @MenelikTucker: It's a Rails extension, I think.

Comment: Your `rmap` doesn't preserve the original `Range` inclusiveness/exclusiveness. For example: `(1...5).rmap(&:to_s) # => "1".."5"`. You should use `Range.new` to define `rmap`, for example: `Range.new(yield(self.begin), yield(self.end), self.exclude_end?)`, this way you would get: `(1...5).rmap(&:to_s) # => "1"..."5"`.

Comment: @undur_gongor: It's in ActiveSupport, actually, the necessary `require` is `'active_support/core_ext/integer/time'`